# how to do an addition after multiplication

Tags: assembly, tasm

So I wanted to make a receipt output where (receipt = receipt + foodtotal). Any suggestions?

```
foodchoice db 0

foodtotal db 0

foodqty db 0

receipt db 0

...

...

@foodcalculate:        

        mov bl, foodchoice
        mov al, foodqty
        mul bl
        aam


        mov foodtotal, al
        mov cx, ax
        add ch, '0'
        add cl, '0'  

        mov ah, 00          ;clear screen
        mov al, 02
        int 10h 
        lea dx, foodprice 
        mov ah, 9
        int 21h


        mov ah, 2
        mov dl, ch
        int 21h               
        mov dl, cl
        int 21h


@receipt:
        ; receipt code goes from here :(
```

Comment: Are you using the Irvine library?  It has a routine for printing integers (WriteDec?).  Otherwise you are going to have to convert your integer to a string yourself before you can use DOS functions to display it.  Neither assembly nor DOS will do that conversion for you (which is why people use higher level languages like C).

Comment: Keep the binary integer representation of the product somewhere else, so you can add to it and print again.  Instead of destroying the only copy (replacing it with ASCII decimal digits) during in printing.